# Really Odd Android App Update Bug

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, google-play

I previously had an android app released on Google Play.  I pushed out another update a couple days ago, but about 80% of the time, when a user tries to update to the new version, it seems to download and install the app correctly, but then displays a blank screen on startup.  This issue doesn't go away until they either restart their phone, or do a full uninstall and reinstall of the app.

I've tried googling around for answers, but it is hard to describe the problem so I haven't found anything.

If anyone has any ideas as to why this might happen I would be really grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a number of things depending on what changed in your update. Has anyone posted any sort of log, or did it happen on your device for you to log? Since it isn't happening on everyone's device it is going to be a tough call just from my minimal experience. Is it possible that the 20% of the people not having the issue had a later version than the one just before your last patch or does your app require an up-to-date version to run (for example they updated from 1.1 to your newest 1.5 instead of from 1.4 to 1.5)? Like I say, may be easier to help with if you can let us know more specifically what was changed.

Comment: Nobody has posted a log or submitted a report because it doesn't actually crash the application, its just as if all the application entailed was a blank screen.  The experiences are from my testing phones, and friends telling me about the problem.

It did not seem to be previous-version specific, people updating from 2 versions ago had the same problem as the previous version.

Also, it seems to be Android version agnostic, problems occurred on 2.3, 3.0, 4.0. and 4.2 phones

Comment: In terms of what changed with the app, a fair amount of .jar support libraries were added, it was compiled for a higher level SDK, and included another android project support library (sliding menu and actionbarsherlock to be specific)

What is puzzling me is that I don't understand why upgrading causes a problem, but a clean install doesn't

Comment: I guess nobody has any ideas :\
Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. It would make more sense if it were consecutive API's. The only thing I can think is that one of the libraries you try to install in the update conflicts with a native library that doesn't get overridden until the phone restarts. I don't know the deeper steps Android takes, but when you do a patch upgrade it may not rebuild the program the way you may think and the library doesn't get installed the way it does when you do a full app install (again all of this is just speculation).